# Is there a way to shrink my pygame code about accelerating a sprite?

Tags: python, pygame

i did a test program that simulates acceleration and I'm wondering if my code could be shorter given that there's quite a lot of repetition ( especially in the acceleration class ).

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
GRAY = pygame.Color('gray12')
display_width, display_height = display.get_size()
x = display_width * 0.45
y = display_height * 0.8
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
accel_x = 0
accel_y = 0
max_speed = 10


class Acceleration(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = display_width * 0.45
        self.y = display_height * 0.8
        self.y_change = 0
        self.x_change = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Player.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move(self, surface):
        self.x_change += accel_x  # Accelerate.
        self.y_change += accel_y

        if abs(self.x_change) >= max_speed:  # If max_speed is exceeded.
            # Normalize the x_change and multiply it with the max_speed.
            self.x_change = self.x_change / abs(self.x_change) * max_speed
        if abs(self.y_change) >= max_speed:
            self.y_change = self.y_change / abs(self.y_change) * max_speed

        # Decelerate if no key is pressed.
        if accel_x == 0:
            self.x_change *= 0.97
            if abs(self.x_change) <= 0.1:
                self.x_change = 0

        if accel_y == 0:
            self.y_change *= 0.97
            if abs(self.y_change) <= 0.1:
                self.y_change = 0

        if 5 < self.x < display_width-(self.image.get_width()+5):
            self.x += self.x_change  # Move the object.

        elif self.x <= 5:
            if self.x_change <= 0:
                self.x_change = 0
            elif self.x_change >= 0:
                self.x += self.x_change  # Move the object.

        elif self.x >= display_width-(self.image.get_width()+5):
            if self.x_change >= 0:
                self.x_change = 0
            elif self.x_change <= 0:
                self.x += self.x_change  # Move the object.

        if 5 < self.y < display_height-(self.image.get_height()+5):
            self.y += self.y_change  # Move the object.

        elif self.y <= 5:
            if self.y_change <= 0:
                self.y_change = 0
            elif self.y_change >= 0:
                self.y += self.y_change

        elif self.y >= display_height-(self.image.get_height()+5):
            if self.y_change >= 0:
                self.y_change = 0
            elif self.y_change <= 0:
                self.y += self.y_change  # Move the object.

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


test1 = Acceleration()

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        # Set the acceleration value.
        accel_x = -0.05
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        accel_x = 0.05
    else:
        accel_x = 0

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and not keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        accel_y = -0.05
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and not keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        accel_y = 0.05
    else:
        accel_y = 0

    display.fill(GRAY)
    test1.move(display)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

I tried using a for loop but i cant figure how to use it in this case and I dont even know if thats the right way of shrinking the code.

Comment: Since this is working code and there is no problem with it, this is more a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, I actually didnt know about Code Review. I'll post it on there. Sorry if it was inapropriate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `1`, otherwise `0`. So you can calculate the resulting movement when 2 keys are pressed with `keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]` and `keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]`.

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    accel_x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 0.05
    accel_y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 0.05

    display.fill(GRAY)
    test1.move(display)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```